# How do you disable or uninstall the "Your PC comes with Alexa Built-in" popup on newer Windows laptops?

Tags: windows, uninstall, lg-gram

We've bought two laptops recently that pop-up a window like this every single time you boot up the computer:

[image]

I've found "Alexa" in the "Apps & features" section of Settings, and clicked "Uninstall" — but after rebooting, the window is still popping up.

How do we disable this permanently?

Comment: What version of WIndows are you running exactly?

Comment: Control Panel>Programs and Features, see if alexa is listed, if it is uninstall it from there.

Comment: @Ramhound ah, I thought I tagged it windows-10

Comment: @Moab mentioned in the text — already did that, no dice. (Also, omg I miss Moab! Best Friends Animal Sanctuary, anyone??)

Comment: You still haven’t indicated what version of Windows 10 your running. Please do NOT, provide this information in a comment, instead edit your question

Comment: Within Settings try and disable “Suggest ways I can finish setting up my device to get the most out of Windows.”

Comment: Does **Task Manager > Startup** tab list any Alexa entries?  If so, disable them.  Otherwise, launch an Administrator Windows PowerShell session and run `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where Name -Like *Alexa* | select Name,PackageFullName`.  If you see any Alexa AppX packages listed, you can pipe the results to `Remove-AppxPackage` to remove them. Reboot afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

From *[leeharvey1's](https://superuser.com/users/1535708/leeharvey1)* [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1695807/how-do-you-disable-or-uninstall-the-your-pc-comes-with-alexa-built-in-popup-on#comment2608210_1695807):

**A)** Launch PowerShell as an administrator and run below command:

**Win10:**

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where Name -Like *Alexa* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage –online | where DisplayName -Like *Alexa* | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online #Removes it from default profile
```

**Win11:** (added `-AllUsers` to ***Remove-AppxPackage***)

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where Name -Like *Alexa* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

**B)** Alternatively, launch PowerShell normally (not admin)

```
Get-AppxPackage | where Name -Like *Alexa* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

--

Additionally, you may want to launch taskmanager and look at startup tab - you may find some unexpected programs there that are set to automatically start up. Ideally yod would uninstall them, but usually can disable them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Windows 11.

Do this:

Start / Settings / Apps / Startup

Turn off 'AlexaBuilt-in'

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: leeharvey1 instructions do not work.  Test on two Windows 11 computers.